Evaluate $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x\,y\,\exp\left({-\frac{1}{2}\left(x-y\right)^2-\frac{y^2}{2}}\right)\,\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y$
I'm currently practicing some problems in probability theory to give me a good base for stochastic processes.
Here, probability density for $Y$ is a Gaussian with zero mean and that for $X$ is a Gaussian whose mean is dependent on $Y$. I'm trying to evaluate the expectation value of, $ \left<XY\right> $ with joint probability density, $$ P(x,y)=P(x|y) P(y)= \dfrac{e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(x-y\right)^2}}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \times \dfrac{e^{-\frac{1}{2}y^2}}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}$$ From my little knowledge, we have $$\left<XY\right>= \int _{-\infty }^{\infty }\int _{-\infty \:}^{\infty \:} x\,y\,P(x,y)\, \mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y\,=\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x\,y\,\exp\left({-\frac{1}{2}\left(x-y\right)^2-\frac{y^2}{2}}\right)\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y$$ I tried to substitute $\,u=x-y\,$ for completing the square and then using the identity, $$\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }x \exp(-\alpha x^2)\,\mathrm{d}x=0$$ But I was unsuccessful because I couldn't separate the variables because of "$x\,y$" inside the integral. Please let me know what I'm doing wrong and also how I can solve the integral. TIA.

Do the variable change:
$$\begin{cases} u &= x-y \\ v &= y \end{cases}$$
We have $du\wedge dv = dx\wedge dy$, hence $$2\pi \langle XY \rangle = {\int_{\mathbb R\times \mathbb R} (u+v) v \exp(-\frac{u^2+v^2}{2})}dudv=\int_{\mathbb R\times\mathbb R}uv \exp(-\frac{u^2+v^2}{2})+\int_{\mathbb R\times \mathbb R} v^2 \exp(-\frac{u^2+v^2}{2})$$
And $$\int_{\mathbb R\times \mathbb R} uv \exp(-\frac{u^2+v^2}{2})=[\int_{\mathbb R} u\exp(-\frac{u^2}{2})du]^2=0$$
Because $u\exp(-u^2/2)$ is an odd function.
Also
$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\mathbb R\times \mathbb R} v^2 \exp(-\frac{u^2+v^2}{2})=[\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{\mathbb R}\exp(-\frac{u^2}{2})du][\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{\mathbb R}v^2\exp(-\frac{v^2}{2})dv]=\langle Y \rangle \langle Y^2\rangle = 1$$

Another way is to recognize that $$\int_{\mathbb R}xP(x|y)dx=y$$
Because obviously, given $Y=y$, $X$ is Gaussian with mean value $y$. Hence
$$\int_{\mathbb R\times\mathbb R} xyP(x|y)P(y)dxdy=\int_{\mathbb R} y^2P(y)dy = \text{Var}(Y) = 1$$

Thanks @just-a-user. The first one makes sense. Btw, mean value of $X$ is not $y$. Its dependent on $y$.

Exactly, it depends on $y$: it is just $y$, conditioning on $Y=y$.

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x\,\exp\left({-\frac{1}{2}\left(x-y\right)^2}\right)\,\mathrm{d}x$$ $$=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(t+y)\,\exp ({-\frac{1}{2} t^{2})}\,\mathrm{d}t$$ $$=0+y\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp ({-\frac{1}{2} t^{2})}\,\mathrm{d}t=\sqrt {2\pi} y.$$
Now integrate $\sqrt {2\pi}y^{2} e^{-\frac {y^{2} }2}$. You get $2\pi$ as the answer .

I don't think the answer is accurate. @geetha290km

@Govind I don't think you read any of the answers correctly. All three answers give the same answer $2\pi$ and all the methods are correct.

$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty dyy\exp\left(-\frac{y^2}{2}\right)
\int_{-\infty}^\infty dxx\exp\left(-\frac{(x-y)^2}{2}\right)=
$$
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty dyy\exp\left(-\frac{y^2}{2}\right)
\int_{-\infty}^\infty du(u+y)\exp\left(-\frac{u^2}{2}\right)=
\sqrt{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty dyy^2\exp\left(-\frac{y^2}{2}\right).
$$

You cannot split up the integral without applying the transformation throughout @jon

@Govind This answer and mine just use Fubini's Thorem and the answers are correct and rigorous. Transformation of variables is not necessary.

@geetha290krm You are right. For correctness, the OP should have given one point to each reply and select the one he liked more.

@Govind Your statement does not make sense, sorry.
